# How can i get the users refering URL on page load? (VB)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

What can i used to get a visiting users referal URL?

I know about retrieving IP address etc but need to log a referal URL (e.g. google) on load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `Reqyest.UrlReferrer`, which may be null.

Answer (score 5):

```
    Dim sUrlReferrer As String = String.Empty

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        If IsNothing(Request.UrlReferrer) Then
            sUrlReferrer = "NOWHERE"
        ElseIf (Request.UrlReferrer.ToString.Length = 0) Then
            sUrlReferrer = "NOWHERE"
        Else
            sUrlReferrer = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Safer method, because Request.UrlReferrer can be null.

```
Dim sUrlReferrer As String
If Not IsPostBack Then
    If (Request.UrlReferrer.ToString.Length = 0) Then
        sUrlReferrer = "NOWHERE"
    Else
        sUrlReferrer = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString
End If
```

Comment: You should check if Request.UrlReferrer is Nothing.  If you try to call a method on Nothing an exception will be thrown.